# Changing the notification field "seen" boolean in firebase to true via a transaction operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up an onClick event to call a function that will change the notification document's field "seen" to true via firebase. When I try to call the function I get an error that says the following:

> Transaction failed:  TypeError: Cannot read property '_delegate' of
> undefined
> at qa (prebuilt-3c03a633-33a12d73.js:16242)
> at e.get (prebuilt-3c03a633-33a12d73.js:16336)
> at t.get (prebuilt-3c03a633-33a12d73.js:17913)
> at Header.js:64

*please note: The property of '_delegate' is found within function from a prebuild file but the error is a snowball effect from what happens on line 64 of Header.js, which I've shown below. The issue is within the 'markNotificationsAsSeen' function.

A suggestion that was given was maybe to change it from a transaction operation to a batched writes operation but I'm not sure. I have included my code below:

```
    const markNotificationsAsSeen = () => {
        var notificationDocRef = db
            .collection("notifications")
            .doc("Ddo1Z3GtgwzytZig1GPD");

        return db
            .runTransaction((transaction) => {
                return transaction.get(notificationDocRef).then((notificationDoc) => {
                    if (!notificationDoc.exists) {
                        throw "Document does not exist!";
                    }

                    const doc = notificationDoc.get();
                    if (
                        doc.user.askerUserId === auth.currentUser.uid &&
                        doc.seen === false
                    ) {
                        console.log("I passed");
                    }
                    // transaction.update(notificationDocRef, { seen: false });
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
            });
    };
```

Comment: Whatever object you are trying to read `_delegate` from is undefined, however, `_delegate` is not in your code here. Please post the code that the error comes from as well.

Comment: need to see the line number corresponding to the error, hopefully also. tell us the process, ex. A -> B -> C -> D. everything starts from `handleQuestion` ? or ?

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail from the error. Let me know if that clarifies things

Comment: You will want to work on making a more concise question/post to get a decent answer.  You've posted way more code than necessary to narrow the problem down to the specific issue.  Please see [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions on getting a solid answer and not get misdirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the only way to call the conditions were to use a .get() along with a .then() in order to call a querysnapshot.

Here is a link incase anyone else bumps into this problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

I was able to solve it by using the following code:

```
const markNotificationsAsSeen = () => {
    var notificationDocRef = db
        .collection("notifications")
        .where("user.askerUserId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid)
        .where("seen", "==", false)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
                    doc.ref.update({ seen: true });
                }
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
};
```